# MySQL query users that login daily at a particular month

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL that stores every users last login time.
Is there any method to query out users that logs in everyday at a particular month?
eg. a list of users that login everyday in January

UPDATE:
Table very simple indeed, just 2 fields:

```
  structure 
  -----------------------
  userid   last_login_time
```

Comment: If you give the structure of your tables, i.e. the columns then it someone can probably help you out. Without that information it is almost impossible to give any concrete answer.

Comment: If you are storing only last login time then it is not possible to validate it against whole month. You need to store data of all logins for a month for a user. May be one entry per day would be enough, if user logins multiple time a day.

Comment: what have you tried? Use subquery and group by login date and user id and then if amount of login dates is same than amount of days in january then select only those users.. something like that. Edit: are you storing every login time or only last login time in table?

Comment: Or use a counter for consecutive days and reset when month changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If `last_login_time` is not actually just the *last* login time, but *all* login times:**

```
SELECT userID
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(last_login_time) = 2 AND YEAR(last_login_time) = 2013
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(last_login_time)) = DAY(LAST_DAY(MAX(last_login_time)))
```

I believe the below allows for indices to be used, so may be more efficient: (if indexed)

```
SELECT userID
FROM table
WHERE last_login_time LIKE '2013-02%'
GROUP BY userID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DAY(last_login_time)) = DAY(LAST_DAY(MAX(last_login_time)))
```

**If `last_login_time` is just the *last* login time:**

Add another column to the table which will be a counter to incidate the number of days logged in this month, update it every time a user logs in on a new day. Reset this counter when a new month starts.

To get users:

```
SELECT userID
FROM table
WHERE last_login_time LIKE '2013-02%'
  AND counter = DAY(last_login_time)
```

Comment: Wonderful!! The queries works for me. Actually "last_login_time" is a log when user logs everytime. I'm going to modify the DB structure for this. But at the meantime I need these query to grab past data. Many thanks to Dukeling!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `MySQL MONTH` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM user_logins ORDER BY MONTH(last_login_time) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

above query will return latest record.

now if latest record is currently logged in date then you can use `LIMIT 1,1` in `LIMIT`,

Answer (score 0):

use following query to get your required result

```
  select * from logindetails lg 
group by userid having month(lg.` last_login_time`)=2  and year(lg.` last_login_time`)=2013 and 
(count(distinct(day(lg.` last_login_time`)))) =day(last_day(lg.` last_login_time`))
```

In the above query 2 represent the month february. If you want march use 3, april use 4 ,.....